# Why does JQuery show() function only work on one (rather than all) of elements with the selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/3buve19w/).

In the following SSCCE, there is a `<table>` nested inside another `<table>`.

The question is about the `click` listener for `#add` button. Specifically, the last `if/else` block of the function. When you run this code, click the `Add TextField` button once (or more times), and you will see that the `#remove` button on which `show()` should be executed, is only *shown* for the first *matched selector*, and not both (or all) of them.

**Ideally the `Remove TextField` should be *shown* for all the `#remove` selectors.**

**The question is why? How do I fix this?**

```js
$(document).on("click", "button#add", function() {
  event.preventDefault();

  var parentTable = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
  var lastTableRow = parentTable.children('tbody').children('tr:last');

  //Adding the new row
  parentTable.children('tbody').append(lastTableRow.clone());

  //Reset lastRow variable 
  lastTableRow = parentTable.children('tbody').children('tr:last');
  //Reset the fields
  lastTableRow.find('table tbody tr td input').each(function() {
    $(this).val('');
  });


  //update numberOfRows variable
  var numberOfRows = parentTable.children('tbody').children('tr').length;
  alert("numberOfRows:" + numberOfRows); //check


  if (!(numberOfRows > 1)) {
    $("#remove").hide();
  } else {
    $("#remove").show();
  }

});
```

```css
#outer-table {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 3px solid pink;
}
#inner-table {
  border: 3px solid orange;
}
#remove {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="outer-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>


        <table id="inner-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p style="display:inline-block">Enter first complain:</p>
                <input type="text" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>

          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <button id="add">Add Textfield</button>
                <button id="remove">Remove Textfield</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>



      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>



  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Table Footer</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

</table>
```

Comment: you are using an id, which only returns one element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're using `id` for a group of objects. `id` should be unique per document. You should use a class name instead.